# Get window back on top

Tags: powershell, xaml, user-interface

I started a new project with XAML based GUI, but I have the problem. When I open another window, message box or even call `Get-Credential`, the main windows disappears in the background (behind all other open windows).

Is there a possible easy way to get the windows back on top?
I found a lot of solutions with `Get-Process`, etc. but that seems to complicated for this simple issue.

Comment: [Maybe related](https://superuser.com/a/769740/156043).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might also be too complicated...
Nevertheless, using the [SetWindowsPos function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
$User32 = Add-Type -Debug:$False -MemberDefinition '
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X,int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
' -Name "User32Functions" -namespace User32Functions -PassThru 

$Xaml = ...
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader($Xaml)))
$Handle = (New-Object System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper($Window)).Handle

[Void]$User32::SetWindowPos($Handle, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x53)
```

Comment: tried this, but worked only partially. it seems to be only a problem in ISE. when i start the script from normal powershell console it worked.